# use phptal to insert value in <input type="text" name="txtname" value="">

Tags: php, phptal

i am first time user of PHPTAL and i am not able to provide value to input box using PHPTAL
i have three files
1.index.php

```
require_once 'includes/lib/PHPTAL-1.2.2/PHPTAL.php';
// create a new template object
$template = new PHPTAL('components/epayroll/new/employeeView.xhtml');
require_once("employeeClass.php");
    $people = array();
    $people[] = new Person("foo"); 
// put some data into the template context
$template->title = 'The title value';
$template->people = $people;        
// execute the template
    try {
    echo $template->execute();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
```

2.empView.Xhtml

```
 <td> <tal:block metal:define-macro="text">  <input name="${name}"
 tal:attributes="id id | nothing" type="text"     value="person/name"
 /> </tal:block> </td>
```

3.empClass.php

```
class Person {
public $name;
function Person($name){
$this->name = $name;
}
}
```

please help me with steps  how to do this.

thanks for your precious response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `employeeView.xhtml` you need to iterate over people:

```
<div tal:repeat="person people">
<!-- you can use person here -->
</div>
```

If you wanted to call the macro, then:

```
<div tal:repeat="person people">
  <div metal:use-macro="text" />
</div>
```

You might also add something like `tal:define="id repeat/person/key"` to the inner `<div>` if you want array keys to be used as IDs.

And to set value of `<input>` use:

```
<input value="${person/name}">
```

which is a short-hand for:

```
<input tal:attributes="value person/name">
```

Comment: Thanks @porneL so far i tried <tr tal:repeat="person people">
           <td class='label'>Name:</td>
          <td class='input' tal:content="person/names"></td>    
     </tr> this worked but still not able to insert value in textbox.  i am new in templating.please guide me in steps so that i can follow it. beside that i am not using <div>:--- thanks once again

Comment: @SajadA oh, I didn't notice that `<input value>` was the problem, I've expanded my answer